# Loop instead of many if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
if( $('.test1').hasClass('collapsed') == false ){
$('.test1').trigger('click');
}
if( $('.test2').hasClass('collapsed') == false ){
$('.test2').trigger('click');
}
if( $('.test3').hasClass('collapsed') == false ){
$('.test3').trigger('click');
}
if( $('.test4').hasClass('collapsed') == false ){
$('.test4').trigger('click');
}
if( $('.test5').hasClass('collapsed') == false ){
$('.test5').trigger('click');
}
```

i have common class test ,is there any way to reduce this if condition to one using loop.

```
for(...){
 if( $('.test[i]').hasClass('collapsed') == false ){
 $('.test[i]').trigger('click');
}
}
```

Please suggest .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you add a second class like `.clickable` to this elements? Then you could just do a

```
if( $('.clickable').hasClass('collapsed') == false ){
   $('.clickable').trigger('click');
}
```

Or, including the comment from the other answer

```
$('.clickable').not('.collapsed').click()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for(...) {
 var id = ".test" + i;
 if( $(id).hasClass('collapsed') == false ) {
      $(id).trigger('click');
 }
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `if` statement: `$(id).filter('.collapsed').click()`

Comment: It should actually be `$(id).not('.collapsed').click()` but same idea.

Comment: $(id).not('.collapsed').click() , this is more than enough for now ,thanks